# C++- Macro definition throwing error

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, directive

I am new to c++ programming. I am trying few things 
I tried using directive in following way as shown in below  program just for trail it is throwing error

IDE used:VS 2015

language :VC++

Project type: library
**Error occured is Error: Expected an identifier**

This is in Stdafx.h

```
#define MANAGED_PUBLIC  public ref
```

This is in  trail.h

```
using namespace System;

namespace trail {

    MANAGED_PUBLIC class Class1
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
}
```

I wanted to use MANAGED_PUBLIC instead of using public ref each and every time in whole project

Comment: Why would you want to do this? `public ref` is well known, MANAGED_PUBLC would rather confuce others. I do not recommend to do so.

Comment: i am modifying some legacy code , They used #define MANAGED_PUBLIC  __gc public and new syntax refers  ' ref ' instead ' '__gc'

Comment: Off-topic but I must say I find `public ref class` a lot easier to read than `MANAGED_PUBLIC class`.  `ref class` screams CLI (which is of critical importance in the design of the library); `MANAGED_PUBLIC`  just screams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. `public ref` is a context sensitive keyword. You cannot bury it down under a macro. C++/CLI compiler would process it differently than a regular compiler hence the macro outcome won't be `public ref`. You must type it everywhere.

You can use two macros:

```
#define MANAGED_PUB public
#define MANAGED_REF ref

MANAGED_PUB MANAGED_REF  class Class1
{
   // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't the macros be replaced by the preprocessor before compilation? Or has MS changed this entirely for C++/CLI?

Comment: I am still finding good source for the answer. But I am sure `#define MANAGED_CLASS ref class` type of thing won't work.

Comment: But the legacy code what i have was using similar syntax with "#define MANAGED_PUBLIC __gc public " htat was supported in .net 2.0

Comment: You may try with old-syntax of Managed C++, but newer version won't allow it.

Comment: I tried finding actual reason of *compiler - pre-processor - compiler* order where macro is not expanded by CLI compiler, hence the error. But failed to locate the source/article/SO question.

Comment: So what could be resolution manually i has to manage every where with public ref instead of using directive?

Comment: See my updated answer which states you need to build two macros.

Comment: i tried same thing it was throwing error saying " Erorr:Expected an identifier"

Comment: Yes, you are right. It still wants `public ref` as single keyword. Replacing it is only good option IMO/

Comment: Actually, [“ref class” is a single token in the lexer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hsutter/2003/11/23/ccli-keywords-under-the-hood/).

Answer (score 0):

You might try a compiler flag: `-DMANAGED_PUBLIC="public ref"` for your legacy code (quotes are stripped according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx)).